# How can i Re-set customized shortkut keys to default keys in corel draw and Adobe Photoshop without re-installation

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, corel-draw

i have just changed my job in my new office when i start work on **Photoshop** and **Corel Draw** the all shorts keys changed is there any option to restore my complete software without installation.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for CorelDraw.

For Photoshop Choose Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts.

Then select "Photoshop Default" from the menu at the top of the dialog window.

Finally, click OK.